# Duplicate main-es2015 file downloaded on page load

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, duplicates, bundle, loading

On refreshing an angular application. In the network tab on filter able to see main-es2015 being shown as downloaded:
[image: Image with the duplicated script]

EDIT:
tsconfig.app.json

```
{
   "extends": "./tsconfig.json", 
   "compilerOptions": { "outDir": "./out-tsc/app", "types": [] },      
   "files": ["src/main.ts", 
   "src/polyfills.ts", 
   "src/typings.d.ts"],  
   "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"], 
   "exclude": ["src/test.ts", "src/**/*.spec.ts", "*/.stories.*"] 
}
```

Comment: What is your question ? What is the problem ? Can you [edit] to add details ?